# Left Join in MySQL wrong output table

Tags: mysql

I did a left join to obtain the data that I wanted. However, the output table has 4 columns, where the first 3 have the right data but the last column doesn't match with the other 3. So, to be specific in one table I have the names and in the other I have dates, usernames, and "comments". What makes it difficult is that I need to have only the most recent dates in a table that is changed daily. This is my query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ur.USR_FIRSTNAME, ur.USR_LASTNAME) AS 'NAME',
       aav.USR AS 'USERNAME',
       IF(aav.TIME_STAMP > NOW() + INTERVAL -4 HOUR,
       aav.AVAILABLE_DATE,MAX(aav.AVAILABLE_DATE)) AS 'DATE_AVAILABLE',
       aav.COMMENTS AS 'COMMENTS'   
FROM wi_workflow.USERS ur LEFT JOIN fii_tables.available_log aav ON    ur.USR_USERNAME = aav.USR and ur.USR_UID = aav.USR_UID
LEFT JOIN fii_tables.available_log aav2 ON(aav.COMMENT = aav2.COMMENT)
WHERE ur.USR_POSITION = 'EDE'
AND ur.USR_STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
AND aav.TIME_STAMP > NOW() + INTERVAL - 45 DAY
GROUP BY 1;
```

Can somebody give me hint on how to have the last column matching the other 2?
Thanks.

Comment: the other problem is that if an old date is greater than the new one in my output table I will have the old greater date and not the new date.

Comment: I think you should show us some sample table data along with your expected output.

Comment: The code doesnt have the " " mistake. when I copied and pasted maybe that ' was erased, but the code runs.

Comment: The output table will be:

Comment: How many columns in the result table? Better give us sample input and output if possible.

Comment: NAmes, USERNAME,DATE_AVAILABLE,COMMENTS. where if I look the comments in the second table they wont match(in the date that they were made) with the comments in the output table.

Comment: There's an edit button

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem this is the query that I used:

```
SELECT aev.ede_name,
           aav.available_date, 
           aav.COMMENT AS 'COMMENT',
           IF(aav.AVAILABLE_DATE < NOW() + INTERVAL 5 DAY, "AVAILABLE THIS WEEK",'NOT AVAILABLE')  AS 'AVAILABILITY'
    FROM fii_tables.available_log aav
    INNER JOIN (SELECT aav.`USR` AS usr,max(aav.TIME_STAMP) AS `TIME_STAMP` from fii_tables.available_log aav group by aav.USR;) lts ON ( lts.usr = aav.usr AND lts.time_stamp = aav.time_stamp )
    LEFT JOIN wf_workflow.actual_ede_v aev ON(aav.usr = aev.usr_username)
    where aev.ede_name is not null
    GROUP BY aav.usr, aav.time_stamp;
```